# trim a source file path

Tags: shell

I need to trim the following path in a unix shell script,please kindly suggest

- input- `/vobs/java/server/forms/data/Branch/semanticexplorer.pls`
- output- `server/forms/data/Branch/semanticexplorer.pls`

Comment: is the directory hierarchy /vobs/java always the same or does it differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not given us any more general criteria by which to trim - so I'm chopping the fixed first two components.

The mechanism like this avoids executing a process:

```
input=/vobs/java/server/forms/data/Branch/semanticexplorer.pls
output=${input#/vobs/java/}
```

Bash has some extensions that would be useful for more general path trimming.  The Korn shell supports the `${var#prefix}` notation.

You can also use:

```
prefix=/vobs/java/
input=/vobs/java/server/forms/data/Branch/semanticexplorer.pls
output=${input#$prefix}
```

This allows you to vary the prefix and still remove it.

---

In most shells, the brute force approach is:

```
input=/vobs/java/server/forms/data/Branch/semanticexplorer.pls
output=$(echo $input | sed "s%/vobs/java/%%")
```

In Bash:

```
input=/vobs/java/server/forms/data/Branch/semanticexplorer.pls
output=$(sed "s%/vobs/java/%%" <<< $input)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $pathname | sed -E 's/\/([^/]*\/){2}//'
```